# error al actualizar con while campos en base de datos

Tags: mysql, while, update

```
    $sql2= "SELECT 
         
         precio,
         idproducto,
         descripcion
         from 
         lineaspresupuestos
         WHERE lineaspresupuestos.idpresupuesto=[gidpresupuesto]";

        //macro de scriptcase que ejecuta el select de arriba
        sc_select(ds, "$sql2"); 

    //aqui comienza el while
    if ({ds} === false)
    {
    echo "Access error. Message =". {ds};
    }
    else
    {
    while (!{ds}->EOF)
    {
    $precio = {ds}->fields[0]*{tasa};

    $update="update lineaspresupuestos set precio=$precio where idpresupuesto=.[gidpresupuesto]";
    //macro de scriptcase para ejecutar el mysql
    sc_exec_sql ($update);
    {ds}->MoveNext(); //avanza al siguiente registro
    }
    {ds}->Close(); //fin del ciclo
    }
```

el problema es que me toma el ultimo valor del array y ese es el que me pone en todos los precios

lo que quiero es que el valor $precio me lo actualice segun el idproducto

ejemplo

idproducto 1
precio     5
descripcion sello

idproducto 2
precio     3
descripcion goma

tasa=2
entonces , lo que hace ahora es el $precio=5 de idproducto 1 lo multiplica por la tasa=2 resultado 10

y con el siguiente igual pero se queda con el valor del ultima linea que seria precio 3 del idproducto 2 total = 6

lo que yo quiero es que en cada producto me actualice en la tabla el valor correspondiente,

Comment: ¿Usas macros en contexto PHP? Nunca había visto algo así ... Pero, si PHP tiene sus propias herramientas y mejores.

Comment: es una macro de SCRIPTCASE un generador de codigo con el que estoy trabajando el lo que hace es ejecutar el sql

Comment: Ya, no sabía que eso existía. Tu código viene a ser, como otro lenguaje dentro de PHP. Si quieres seguir con esto, pon la etiqueta de scriptcase a la pregunta, pero esto NO es PHP y en PHP NO se leen registros así. No sé si haces esto por simplificar, pero lo cierto es que así no aprendes PHP y usas un intermediario, produciendo, quizá, un código más lento.

Comment: ok entiendo..pues tengo que ponerme mas con php, siempre he trabajo con scriptcase y realemnte tengo poco tiempo, y me ha permitido hacer varios sistemas rapidamente, le agrego entonces scriptcase a ver si me pueden ayudar por aqui.

Comment: Sí, debes poner Scriptcase, porque el problema es a nivel de ese código. Por otra parte, tú puedes hacer un `UPDATE` basado en una consulta `SELECT`, o sea, puede que no necesites dos consultas para este caso.